# Welches Verb passt hier?

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Am Morgen breite ich mich einen Sandwich zu
>
> Am Morgen mache ich (mir) einen Sandwich.

Beim zweiten Satz bin ich mir unsicher, ob ich ein "mir" schreiben kann.

Comment: *zubEreiten* nicht *zubreiten* und *mir* nicht *mich*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `etwas zubereiten` and `etwas machen` are possible here as well as `jemandem etwas zubereiten` and `jemandem etwas machen`.

> Am Morgen bereite ich *mir* ein Sandwich zu.
>
> Am Morgen bereite ich ein Sandwich zu.
>
> Am Morgen mache ich *mir* ein Sandwich.
>
> Am Morgen mache ich ein Sandwich.

Comment: To add to that I find "zubereiten" in context with a sandwich a bit over the top... either the sandwich is very very fancy or your language is if you phrase it that way

Comment: @Emanuel Deutsche *machen* Sandwichs meistens recht langweilig. In anderen Ländern können das aber schon Kunstwerke sein.